# What does transition property with all mean using css and react?

Tags: css, reactjs

i am new to animation. i want to understand what a piece of code does.

i have the code like below

```
const Dialog = styled.div`
    background: grey;
    box-shadow: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 380px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 200px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 600ms ease-in-out; //on what all properties does all apply to
`;
```

Now looking at above code, i am not sure on what all properties does transition all apply to in this case.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: "All" means exactly what it says, if the element has a property (whether stated or implicit) that *can* be transitioned , it will.

Comment: thanks. but i want to replace all with the individual transition properties there. how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transition: all 600ms ease-in-out;` Here **all** is taking all the properties to animate it. In your case it is like make transition on all properties like background, border etc.

You can use multiple specific properties for transition like this:

```
transition: margin-right 2s, color 1s; //<--from mdn doc
```

[Form more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Comment: thanks in my example all have the same duration like 600ms. could you show how to write that.

Comment: @stack_overflow You can use this `.6s`.